# animation not positioned correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do an animation with the next code:

```css
.slogan {
    width: 73.5%;
    color: black;
}
.left-slogan {
    font-size: 7vw;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.left-slogan > p {
    line-height: 0;
}
.left-slogan {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 24px;
}
.right-slogan span {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: black;
    font-size: 7vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-animation: rotateWord 15s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: rotateWord 15s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: rotateWord 15s linear infinite 0s;
}
.right-slogan span:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
.right-slogan span:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}
.right-slogan span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.right-slogan span:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
    animation-delay: 9s;
}
.right-slogan span:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateWord {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    2% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    }
    5% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
    }
    80% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotateWord {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    2% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
    }
    5% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateY(30px);
    }
    80% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes rotateWord {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    2% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
        transform: translateY(-30px);
    }
    5% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
        transform: translateY(30px);
    }
    80% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="slogan">
    <div class="left-slogan">
        <p>We are
            <div class="right-slogan"> 
                <span id="aux-word">testing</span>
                <span id="aux-word">experiencing</span>
                <span id="aux-word">checking</span>
                <span id="aux-word">solving</span>
            </div>
        </p>
        <p>a bug</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

For any reason, the animated text is not positioned at the right side of the words "We are" even though it's animated.

Could anybody make me know how to solve it?

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `right-slogan` `div` is acting as a block element.  If you can make this a `span` instead, it will layout inline with the other text.  A couple other CSS tweaks below to get things laid out nicely (removed the `overflow:hidden` and added a `margin-left`).

```css
.slogan {
    width: 73.5%;
    color: black;
}
.left-slogan {
    font-size: 7vw;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.left-slogan > p {
    line-height: 0;
}
.left-slogan {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 24px;
}

.right-slogan span {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 7vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-animation: rotateWord 15s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: rotateWord 15s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: rotateWord 15s linear infinite 0s;
}
.right-slogan span:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
.right-slogan span:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}
.right-slogan span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.right-slogan span:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
    animation-delay: 9s;
}
.right-slogan span:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateWord {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    2% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    }
    5% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
    }
    80% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotateWord {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    2% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
    }
    5% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateY(30px);
    }
    80% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes rotateWord {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    2% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
        transform: translateY(-30px);
    }
    5% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
        transform: translateY(30px);
    }
    80% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="slogan">
    <div class="left-slogan">
        <p>We are
            <span class="right-slogan"> 
                <span id="aux-word">testing</span>
                <span id="aux-word">experiencing</span>
                <span id="aux-word">checking</span>
                <span id="aux-word">solving</span>
            </span>
        </p>
        <p>a bug</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that was such an useful answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make some changes as follows:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotateWord {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    2% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-200%);
    }
    5% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-180%);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-140%);
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-140%);
    }
    80% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Add a white space between "We are" and the animated text:

```
        <span id="aux-word">&nbsp;testing</span>
        <span id="aux-word">&nbsp;experiencing</span>
        <span id="aux-word">&nbsp;checking</span>
        <span id="aux-word">&nbsp;solving</span>
```

Comment: Even though your solution was okay and useful, the main problem was that the `<div class="right-slogan"> didn't form part of the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes in CSS to overwrite default browser css

```
body {
margin: 0px; // to overwrite any margin given by browsers
}
.left-slogan > p {  // removed line-height style
-webkit-margin-after: 0px; // to overwrite any margin given by webkit  browsers
-webkit-margin-before: 0px;
}
.right-slogan span {
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
overflow: hidden;
color: black;
font-size: 7vw;
font-weight: bold;
-webkit-animation: rotateWord 15s linear infinite 0s;
-ms-animation: rotateWord 15s linear infinite 0s;
animation: rotateWord 15s linear infinite 0s;
top: 0;  // added top position to zero
}
```